# Issue with saving spl characters like '<' '>' in textbox field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a issue in saving spl characters like '<' '>'  in my production server.

I don't see the same issue on my local server as I made < Page validaterequest="false"/> in web.config file.But when I try the same changes in my production server the data is not saved with spl characters.

since I understand that the code is developed on .netframework 3.5,i did not develop the code(I am new to coding too :))

My production server environment details are: Windows server 2012,IIS 8.

Please do let me know If i have to share anymore details regarding my issue,and please suggest a solution,if you understand what my issues is all,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running a newer version of .NET on your server. The ValidateRequest property requires RequestValidationMode="2.0" in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

> - 4.0 (the default). The HttpRequest object internally sets a flag that indicates that request validation should be triggered whenever any HTTP request data is accessed. This guarantees that the request validation is triggered before data such as cookies and URLs are accessed during the request. **The request validation settings of the pages element (if any) in the configuration file or of the @ Page directive in an individual page are ignored.**
> - 2.0. Request validation is enabled only for pages, not for all HTTP requests. **In addition, the request validation settings of the pages element (if any) in the configuration file or of the @ Page directive in an individual page are used to determine which page requests to validate.**

Source: [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestValidationMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode(VS.100).aspx) with my emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

I think Simon has your answer but as a side note:

By allowing < and > characters and setting `validaterequest="false"` you're opening your code up to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), never trust user input not even on intranet sites. If you keep this make sure you heavily sanitise the input.

If you're wanting the tag characters for formatting (CMS?) then you may want to strongly consider an alternative such as [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) as it'd also be easier for your users.